# setstate - dynamic key values - overwriting not merging state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested state object I'm trying to update dynamically, but when i update the final value is overwritten not updated.

My current code looks like:

```
inputChangeHandler = (event, key) => {
  const value = event.target.value
  this.setState({
    formData: {
          [`${key}`]: {
            [event.target.id]: value
          }
    }
  })
}
```

When the state is updated, the state updates from (for example):

```
formData:{ 
    key1: {
        id: value1
    }
}
```

to:

```
formData:{ 
    key1 {
        id2: value2
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
formData:{ 
    key1 {
        id: value1
        id2: value2
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> overwriting not merging state

[**State merging is shallow**.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged).

It modifies the same `formData` key.

So the previous `formData` state  should be used to properly construct the new `formData` state.

```
inputChangeHandler = (event, key) => {
  const value = event.target.value
  const id = event.target.id

  setState((prevState) => ({
    formData: {
      ...prevState.formData,
      [key]: {
        ...prevState.formData[key]
        [id]: value, // append id value under key
      }
    }
  }))
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works great.

Comment: Glad to be of help @ScottWaddell!

Answer (score 0):

try this. You need to use prevState, and then merge that prevState with your new state.

```
inputChangeHandler = (event, key) => {
    const value = event.target.value

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      formData: {
        ...prevState.formData,
        [`${key}`]: {
          ...prevState.formData[`${key}`], // include prevState's nested key vals
          [event.target.id]: value
          }
      }})
    )
  }
```

Comment: This won't merge existing keys in `formData`. This will only contain one key.